# How to add multiple jars under one dependency in jfrog Atrifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have two dependent files, in one dependency like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But when *mvn install* from Maven repository I'm getting two files **"spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar & spring-context-support-3.0.7.RELEASE"** Same thing how to upload to Atrifactory?
I'm using artifactory-3.8.0 version.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your build generates 2 files and you want to archive both in your Artifactory server?

Comment: yes, you are right Bruno

Comment: Did you have a look to the Build Helper Maven Plugin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789671/how-to-publish-multiple-jar-files-to-maven-on-a-clean-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded all dependencies from maven repository. And i imported to my Atrifactory repository from my local maven repository. That works for me.

Comment: You can configure a [remote repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) to easily achieve the same goal